# Could not assign the dynamic value in testcasesource

Tags: c#, nunit, testcasesource

I developed single test case using testcasesource. Already read data from excel and stored in array. Now I want to assign the array values for testcasesource dynamically.How can i do that? This is my code.

```
[TestFixture]
class testcases 
{
    static String[] inputdata= readdata("Inputdata.xls", "DATA", "TestCase1");
    static object[] exceldata = { new object[] {inputdata} };

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        //setup code here
    }

    [Test]
    [TestCaseSource("exceldata")]
    public void Sample(String Username,String password,String FirstName)
    {
               // test code here
    }   

    [TearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        tstlogic.driverquit();
    }
}
```

I have 3 input values in inputdata array i need to assign these value for testcasesource. Can anyone help?

Comment: Where are `String Username,String password,String FirstName` are supposed to come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the following line. It defines the wrong type. Unfortunately this is hard to see when `object[]` is used.

```
static object[] exceldata = { new object[] {inputdata} };
// type is object[] of object[] of string[]
```

Should be:

```
static object[] exceldata = { inputdata };
// type is object[] of string[]
```